# Please help me decipher STL autocomplete suggestions

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I use the MSVC with STL on VS. The autocomplete suggestions that it gives is giving me grief. Can you please break this suggestion for the `std::transform` function?

```
_OutTy * transform<_InIt1, _InTy, _InSize, _OutTy, _OutSize, _Fn2>
(_InIt1 _First1, _InIt1 _Last1, _InTy (&_First2)[_InSize], _OutTy(&_Dest)[_OutSize], _Fn2 _Func)
```

**Edit**: I am sorry but I should have been clearer. I saw the transform's documentation. I wanted someone to break down the various symbols in the above sentence.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the documentation for std::transform insufficient?

Comment: There's no "hungarian notation" here; the underscores just make sure the names don't conflict with any legitimate user-defined names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_OutTy* // output type   
transform<_InIt1, // input iterator type for first range
          _InTy, _InSize, // input and size type for second range (array)
          _OutTy, _OutSize, // output and size type for output range (array)
          _Fn2> // transformation function object type
(_InIt1 _First1, _InIt1 _Last1, // first and last iterators for first range
 _InTy (&_First2)[_InSize], // array for second range
 _OutTy(&_Dest)[_OutSize], // array for output range
 _Fn2 _Func) // transformation function object
```

My recommendation: don't waste your time doing this. It took me several minutes just to break that down myself, and I'm used to this stuff. Get quick access to the docs as suggested in other posts.

If you want to be able to decipher MSVC's C++ library implementation, it helps to look through their headers rather than just the intellisense. You'll pick up on some of the common conventions they use, like `InIt` for input iterator, `RanIt` for random-access iterator, etc. It's also essential to understand the basic STL concepts like Sequences, Input Iterators, Bidirectional Iterators, etc. Here's a rather dated but still nice and carefully worded reference: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html

The thing to note about this overload is that the second range and output range are arrays whose sizes are deduced automatically, while the first range is specified normally as a couple of iterators pointing to the start and end of the range. Otherwise the first three parameters would be input iterators and the fourth and return type would be an output iterator.

Answer (score 3):

The suggested overload is a specialization for the case where the 3rd and 4th arguments are both arrays. `_InTy (&_First2)[_InSize]` is more readable as `InType (&Second)[InputLength]`, i.e. `Second` is a reference to an array of type `InType[InputLength]`.

The advantage of this specialization is that the compiler knows the length of the second input sequence. The main overload just has a templated `InputIterator BeginOfSecond` argument, but no `EndOfSecond` argument.

Similarly, `_OutTy(&_Dest)[_OutSize]` allows the compiler to detect the length of the output sequence if that's an array.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated reference from cplusplus.com to cppreference.com**

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

```
template< class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2, class OutputIterator, class BinaryOperation >
OutputIterator transform( InputIterator1 first1, 
                          InputIterator1 last1,
                          InputIterator2 first2, 
                          OutputIterator d_first, 
                          BinaryOperation binary_op );
```

### Parameters

- **first1, last1**  -   the first range of elements to transform
- **first2**     -   the beginning of the second range of elements to transform
- **d_first**    -   the beginning of the destination range, may be equal to first1 or first2
- **binary_op**  -   binary operation function object that will be applied. 
  The signature of the function should be equivalent to the following:
  `Ret fun(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);`
  The signature does not need to have const &. 
  The types  Type1 and  Type2 must be such that objects of types InputIterator1 and InputIterator2 can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to  Type1 and  Type2 respectively. The type  Ret must be such that an object of type OutputIterator can be dereferenced and assigned a value of type  Ret. ​

### Return value

- output iterator to the element past the last element transformed.

Hope that helps

Comment: I am sorry but I should have been clearer. I saw the transform's documentation. I wanted someone to break down the various hungarian notations and symbols in the above sentence.

Comment: @kunj2aan:  The documentation matches what you are seeing in Intellisense.  I don't understand what you're not understanding.

Comment: @Jeffery Please do not reference cplusplus.com. It's been known to have errors. Instead, you should link to cppreference.com. See also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/88241/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact C++ Intellisense is a pain sometimes. Therefore I recommend hitting F1 or searching for std::transform on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/391xya49%28v=VS.71%29.aspx wich gives following explanation:

```
_First1
    An input iterator addressing the position of the first element in the first source range to be operated on.
_Last1
    An input iterator addressing the position one past the final element in the first source range operated on.
_First2
    An input iterator addressing the position of the first element in the second source range to be operated on.
_Result
    An output iterator addressing the position of the first element in the destination range.
_Func
    User-defined unary function object used in the first version of the algorithm that is applied to each element in the first source range or A user-defined (UD) binary function object used in the second version of the algorithm that is applied pairwise, in a forward order, to the two source ranges.
```